# I need to post a file to php via ajax .Im not able to do

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code
On clicking browse and select an image, I should get the image details

(function () {

```
var input = document.getElementById("uploaded_file");




    formdata = false;
```

alert("s");

```
    formdata = new FormData();





input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {alert("AS");




    var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;






    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {




        file = this.files[i];






            if (formdata) {





                formdata.append("images[]", file);





            }






    }






    if (formdata) {





        $.ajax({





            url: "upload.php",





            type: "POST",





            data: formdata,




            processData: false,





            contentType: false,




            success: function (res) {




                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res; 




            }





        });




    }





}, false);
```

}());

Here an error is getting "Input is null'  in mozilla

If In php, I can Take $_FILES...but I need to take in other way itself

Comment: I think Ajax can not upload(Post file to server). You might need to have a form enclosing your file control and then submit that form to a hidden IFrame. It will look like file was uploaded through AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Your selected file will be located here

```
$('input[type="file"]')[0].files[0]
```

Ajax

```
$('input[type="file"]').on('change',function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'upload.php',
        data:{file:this.files[0]},
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            //validation here.
            if(this.files[0].size>5120){
                xhr.abort();
                console.log('file was too large');
            }
        },
        success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Using jQuery selectors and event handlers are easier than using standard javascript ones. But! The above method I've provide will only work with 1.7 and higher. Don't forget to wrap your jQuery functions within a document ready function like below. The below method will work for 1.6.4.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'upload.php',
            data:{file:$(this).files[0]},//not sure if 'this' will work within this function
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
                if($(this).files[0].size>5120){
                    xhr.abort();//stops the ajax from executing
                }
            },
            success:function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });      
});
```

Selector and event listeners are easier to apply to DOM elements using the jQuery library.

```
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(){/*Ajax here*/});
```

is a selector with an event listener in jQuery. Similar to that of following:

```
eles=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
    if(ele[i].getAttribute('type')=='file')ele[i].addEventListener('change',function(){/*Ajax here*/},false);
}
```

Sort of like that. It's probably a lot more complex that what I've written above. [More on jQuery selectors.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

I can't remember much on `formData` but I've written something like this before

```
var data=new formData();
jQuery.each($('input[type="file"]')[0].files,function(i,file){data.append('file-'+i,file);});
```

This way multiple files are appended to `data`. I haven't come across a problem so far sending solely `files[0]`. But there must be a reason I used `formData` in the past.

Comment: var input = document.getElementById('uploaded_file');
    formdata = false;

    formdata = new FormData();
   
  input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {alert("AS");
   var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;
 
  for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
   file = this.files[i];
 
    if (formdata) {
     formdata.append("images[]", file);
    }

Comment: if (formdata) {
   $.ajax({
    url: "upload.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (res) {
     document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res; 
    }
   });
  }

Comment: }, false);
    }());
but  its returns null on loading the page itself.The error is 'input is null'.Is this a problem with my jquery library                                                                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   I am using Mozilla browser

Comment: @linn I can't read that very well. I'll give you an example of what I think you're trying to achieve, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @linn that's alright. Is that anything like what you was trying to create?

Comment: (Please try to avoid large amounts of code in comments, as they don't render well. If you have short snippets in comments, at least wrap them in backticks, so they `look like code`. If you have larger chunks, consider an external pasteboard, or an update to the original question).

Comment: Hi, I hope u know my requirement.Let me breif it again .I need to send a file to php via AJAX.I dont need normal form post method.I.e by using $_FILES.I got a code which meets this.But working on mine

Comment: @linn not sure I understand. `$_FILES` I think requires formData? Not sure? I have been able to send a file and validate it using `$_FILES` without using formData so? I'm not sure.